# Extract date from string/text column in Python

Tags: python, datetime, text-extraction

I have a dataset like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Susan', 'Tom', 'Mike', 'Charles'], 'program': ['Cyber_Security_1/1/2021_Cohort', 'UX_UI_10/20/2020_Cohort', 'not_available', 'Full_Stack_10/9/21_Cohort']})
print(df)

      name                            program
0    Susan     Cyber_Security_1/1/2021_Cohort
1      Tom            UX_UI_10/20/2020_Cohort
2     Mike                      not_available
3  Charles          Fall_Stack_10/9/21_Cohort (Updated on 8/5/2021)
```

(Previous Situation)
I tried to extract the date using `df['date'] = df['program'].str.extract('(../../....)', expand=True)` or  `df['program'].str.extract('(./../....)', expand=True)`.

Next I tried to convert this date column into datetime type using `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')`. But I got errors like the following:

`ValueError: time data '_4/24/2020' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)`
`ValueError: time data '0/20/2020' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)`

(Current Situation)
The previous question listed above is solved by @Tim Biegeleisen and @MrFuppes. However, I soon discovered that I missed the exception `(10/8/21)`. Can anyone help here? Thanks!

I want my result to look like the following:

```
      name                           program           date
0    Susan    Cyber_Security_1/1/2021_Cohort     2021-01-01
1      Tom           UX_UI_10/20/2020_Cohort     2020-10-20
2     Mike                     not_available            NaT
3. Charles         Fall_Stack_10/9/21_Cohort     2021-10-09 (Updated on 8/5/2021)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.extract` with the regex pattern `\d+/\d+/\d{4}`:

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["program"].str.extract(r'(\d+/\d+/\d{4})'), format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Hi Tim - I tried the code you suggested, but in vain. It returns ```AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'```

Comment: @Kate extract the date string to a new df column first, *then* parse that to datetime in a second step.

Comment: @MrFuppes Feel free to edit my answer (or post your own) if you're very certain of this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm certain that it works on my system, but at the moment I don't have an explanation *why* it works in two separate assignments but not in one - so I'll leave it as a comment for now ;-) Let's see if it works for the OP.

Comment: @MrFuppes I followed what you did - running the code separately- and it worked!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your solution is correct! Thanks! I'm not sure if it's too much to ask, but I have the same question that MrFuppes has. Why can't we run the code in just one line?